# Batch file with remote drive python script

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I was working on a python script that I want to run via the task manager. I created a batch file like this:

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe" "\\insert_path_here\project_directory.py"
pause
```

When I have the `project_directory.py` as a path on my hard drive, it works fine with either the task manager or manually opening the batch file. When I put the .py file on a remote drive, the batch file still executes correctly when I manually open it. When the task manager tries runs the `.bat` file, I get a message asking which application I want to use to run the program:

[image]

What do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cmd.exe`. on default you should find it here: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`.

On the side note explore option of converting `.py` to `.exe`, you can start here: https://www.simplifiedpython.net/convert-python-to-exe-tutorial/
I feel like it would be better option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not quite sure what you mean by use `cmd.exe`. I tried that tutorial a bit but it seemed to be copying my entire anaconda library to the location and failed when it didn't have some particular library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying to run the python.exe and then the project_directory.py file separately.  Try putting those in as one command:

```
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe \insert_path_here\project_directory.py"
```

You probably have *.py files already associated with Python on your local machine which is why it works there.

Comment: Hmmm... that didn't seem to work for me. It's telling me that the system cannot find the path specified. You meant that as one path for to python, then a space, then the path to the script? Thanks for trying!

Comment: Ah I see, I missed an important point in your question, sorry.  If you just manually run the python file outside of a virtual environment, does the OS recognize the .py extension and start it with the appropriate program if you don't preface the command with "python.exe"? IOW just run `\insert_path_here\project_directory.py` by itself.

Comment: Well I figured it out and I ain't proud. The problem was that the task scheduler was pointing at the python script, not the .bat file. Thanks for trying though, your prodding got me there indirectly so have the bounty.

Comment: Thank you for that, I appreciate it.  When things like that happen to me I tell myself that it's better to spend a week fixing what turns out to be a silly mistake, than to spend a week on it and not fix it at all.  I'm glad you got it working.